# Is there a name for this type of graph and can this be created using a chart engine?

Tags: graph, highcharts, chart.js, google-visualization, apexcharts

I saw this kind of graphs a few decades ago being used in an automotive industry book written in the 1980s and been more or less fascinated by them ever since, wondering how to create similar timelines on the fly. It would be extremely useful in my upcoming hobby project as I see no other good way to perfectly visualize this type of data.

Attached a simple mock-up (actually very much like how the chart is supposed to look), along with the sample data the chart is based on.

[product evolution chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H8XVK.png)
[product evolution table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/27uEZ.png)

The product characteristic on the Y axis could be many things, like engine power, weight, volume, length, max speed, it's not really important what it is, I just named it capacity here. But it needs to be there to properly align the products on the chart, so a typical timeline with no actual Y axis values is just not enough for the purpose.
I also thought could this thing be tackled with just labeled data series or something, sorry for not knowing the proper terms.

So, I'm mainly interested in knowing the name of this chart variant and are there any examples online. I have searched but haven't really found what I'm looking for.

Secondly, could something like this be accomplished using any of these chart engines:
Google Charts, HighCharts, Chart.js, ApexCharts, or Apache ECharts.

I'm thinking about publishing on WordPress, but MediaWiki or some another popular platform is not completely out of the question either. However, figuring out this graph challenge is naturally the first step here.
The project would be a community effort, but the contributors shouldn't have to worry about any chart creation, just inputting tabular data.

I would highly appreciate any possible answers or tips.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Enough detail, well that's in the attached mock-up chart... should be perfectly enough :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create such a chart with the Highcharts library using a `columnrange` series.

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'columnrange',
    inverted: true
  },
  colors: ['black'],
  title: {
    text: 'Product evolution 1985 - 2000'
  },
  legend: {
    enabled: false
  },
  xAxis: {
    /* min: 50,
    max: 600, */
    tickInterval: 50,
  },
  data: {
    csv: document.getElementById('csv').innerHTML,
    seriesMapping: [{
      x: 0,
      low: 1,
      high: 2,
      label: 3
    }]
  },
  yAxis: {
    title: {
        text: ''
    }
  },
  tooltip: {
    useHTML: true,
    formatter: function() {
      const point = this;

      return `
        <div>
            <b>${point.point.label}</b><br/>
          Capacity: ${point.point.x}<br/>
          Range: ${point.point.low} - ${point.point.high}
        </div>
      `;
    }
  },
  plotOptions: {
    columnrange: {
        groupPadding: 0,
      pointPadding: 0,
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        inside: true,
        formatter: function(e) {
          if (e.align == "left") return this.point.label;
        }
      }
    }
  },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/11.3/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/11.3/highcharts-more.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/11.3/modules/data.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
<pre id="csv" style="display:none">
Capacity, Released, Discontinued, Product
50,
100, 1986, 1994, AB 1
150, 1994, 1997, AC 1
200, 1988, 1994, AB 2
250, 1994, 1997, AC 2
300, 1989, 1991, BH 3
350, 1991, 1995, BK 3
450, 1995, 1999, CC 5
500, 1993, 1995, CB 5
600
</pre>
```

**Demo**: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/4der19cw/ 
**API**: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/data

Comment: Unbelievable, this is exactly what I needed.

Comment: Even better than I was hoping for.
And a no-brainer to accept as an answer, no need to start experimenting if this or that suggested chart type might be suitable or not.

I just knew someone here would be kind enough to dig a bit into this and provide a way to accomplish the desired result. I also was quite sure there are no out-of-the-box easy answers, the chart in question clearly is somehow uncommon in nature, therefore I believe there might be no proper name for it either.

I can't thank you enough.